# Is it possible to use a SID in the WinNT Service Provider?

Tags: c#, windows, account, service-provider, sid

Is there any way to use a SID in the WinNT service provider like:

```
// doesn't work
using (DirectoryEntry groupEntry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://./<SID=S-1-5-32-544>,group"))
{
    
}
```

or do I need to convert the SID to the group name first?

(Using LDAP is not possible in my case)

Comment: When you say that you can't use LDAP, do you mean that you can't use an LDAP-based path?

Comment: @Martin the machine is no domain member

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just to clarify, are you accessing directory entries in a domain then?

Comment: @Martin no, I am accessing local accounts on a standalone machine